# Проброс FTP на Ubuntu через iptables

Tags: iptables, ftp, ubuntu

Добавил правило в секцию *nat
-A PREROUTING -d ${WAN_ADDR} -p tcp --dport 21 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.10.11
Добавил правило в секцию* filter-A FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -d 10.10.10.11 -j ACCEPT

Выполнил команды:
modprobe ip_conntrack
modprobe ip_conntrack_ftp
modprobe iptable_nat
modprobe ip_nat_ftp

Но из вне все равно не получается подключиться ни в активном ни в пассивном режиме...
Указанный IP - это NAS с FTP-сервером.

Что ещё нужно что бы завести наконец доступ извне в локальный FTP ?

PS Ubuntu 10.04, старая конечно, но в данный момент нужно именно на ней...

Answer (score 1):

попробуй прокинуть еще 20 порт и подключится в пассивном режиме